# Generating a Certificate Signing Request for an Apache webserver on a sub domain?

Tags: tls, certificates

I'm reading the instructions for [generating a CSR](https://www.godaddy.com/help/generating-a-certificate-signing-request-csr-apache-2x-5269), and it reads that:

> "Replace yourdomain with the domain name you're securing. For example,
>   if your domain name is coolexample.com, you would type coolexample.key
>   and coolexample.csr."

I realize that this is all just filenames that will be read by my server, but to stick to the convension, if I'm securing a single server and not an entire domain, then would I include the hostname in the name of the private key and the csr?

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth:

Here's what I do:

The chain of trust for https://example.com/ including end-entity certificate and root CA certificate has 3 certs. And I would name them as such:

- `0.example.com.cer`
- `1.intermediate.cer`
- `2.root.cer`

Why? Because then a directory listing gives them in the correct order straight away. And `.cer` is the default Windows file extension.

And for the key:

- `0.example.com.key`

And for the request:

- `0.example.com.req`

Now why not `.csr`? Because Windows CA wants `.req` and Unix/Linux CAs don't care either way. So REQ it is.

## Subdomain in name or not?

Include what makes it easier for you to remember. "example.com" is actually not the `CommonName` for that cert. That would have been `www.example.org`. And I still chose to go with the example.com name, because that is what I remember that site as best.

So if it matters to you, if that helps you keep things apart, then include it.

Answer (score 0):

The name and extension isn't really important.
What matters to sign your Web Server is the **Common Name** and **Subject Alternative Name (SAN)**. You can specify your WebServer hostname, FQDN, aliases (www.hostname) and public IP address (not recommended).

The SAN can be specified using different method, on microsoft CA, you can specify it while pasting the CSR content into the web interface.
[image]

In "additional attributes", type:

```
san:dns=dns.name[&dns=dns.name]
```

e.q. san:dns=yourwebserv&dns=www.yourwebserv&dns=yourwebserv.domain.tld

---

I personnaly use a config file, specify "subjectAltName" and generate my CSR using this command:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -out certificate_b64.cer -keyout private.key -config <Config file>
```

Config File:

```
[ req ]
default_md = sha512
default_bits = 2048
default_keyfile = private.key
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
encrypt_key = no
prompt = no
string_mask = nombstr
req_extensions = v3_req
input_password = <password>
output_password = <password>

[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:false
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, clientAuth
subjectAltName = DNS:<hostname>, IP:<OptionalIP>, DNS:<serverFQDN>

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName = <AU>
stateOrProvinceName = <ServerCounty>
localityName = <ServerTown>
0.organizationName = <organizationName >
organizationalUnitName = <organizationalUnitName >
commonName = <ServerFQDN>
```

---

It is a quite confusing as you can find all sort of different format for SSL material (CSR, Certificate, Private Key)

The common base is the following, in order to get a signed certificate --which is your  goal-- to use on your web server, you need to:

- Generate or import a CSR.
  While generating a CSR, a private key is created (used to decrypt)
- Submit this CSR (plain-text) to a Certificate Authority (CA)

The file can have any extension and any name, you can either submit the file to the CA, or open it with a text editor, copy and paste its content in the CA Web Interface.

- Retrieve the certificate from your CA and implement it for your web server. (used to encrypt)

---

Once you have submitted your CSR, you can delete the file because it is of no use and all that your web server need is certificates (your certificate+CA intermediate+CA  root, called certificate chain) and a private key.

Your Web Server need to know what/where is the private key, and what/where is the certificate so it might rely on extensions and need to be saved in a specific location, a specific format. I would refer you to your Web Server documentation (Nginx, Apache, IIS ?) to find out.

Finally GoDaddy explains you how to generate a CSR and private key, but sometimes your web server or appliance can do this for you via a GUI, and all you need to do is download a CSR (Import), and submit it to your CA.

Please find below a link that explains the different SSL format, and how to check/convert SSL material:
http://bidabe.zapto.org/?p=486

Comment: Your description of SSL encryption is wrong.

Comment: Your comment is worthless

Comment: Sorry. Was the best I could do on my mobile. And not worthless. It told others to not trust your SSL explanation. Private keys are not used for encryption if a [DH key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman_key_exchange) is being used. In that case they're just used for authentication. DH key exchanges are becoming increasingly popular due to their [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy). ([Wikipedia SSL article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy))

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, this is valid. On the other hand I hardly see the point of explaining how asymmetric cryptography is used to secure the exchange of a symmetric encryption to someone new to SSL.